# How to read CSS specification?

Tags: css

I found the [CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/). However, it seems that I should be reading some CSS3 specification which I cannot find. The reason for that is everybody is asking are you using CSS3? Frankly, I'm confused about what to read to have a good understanding of CSS. I think that the specification is the best resource but I can't find CSS3 specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS3 specification is split into modules, a list of which you can find [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work.en.html).

CSS2.1 is the base recommendation from which most new modules extend (and supersede), and is what most browsers implement especially in areas with little CSS3 support as yet. If you have a good understanding of CSS2.1 then you have most of it covered, and you should not have too much trouble with the new modules (and neither should browsers other than Google Chrome).

Some modules have completed and reached Recommendation status; you can find a list of these in the above link under Completed, or with descriptions [here](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#completed). These replace their respective CSS2.1 sections, so for example [Selectors level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) supersedes [CSS2.1 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html).

Comment: So should I start out with reading the entire CSS2.1 specification and them exploring the various modules that reached Recommendation status to see what changed? In general, I'm looking for an approach to take for reading the specifications.

Comment: That's basically what I do (except replace "the entire" with "most of the"). Note also that implementations start during the CR phase for most and some even during the draft stages - refer to http://caniuse.com for browser support tables - so it's useful to look at those drafts as well.